# How do I call a method from an extend Class in Java?

Tags: java, extends

I have a general Class called "Message":

```
public abstract class Message {

    private int type;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;
    
    public Message(int type, String origin, String destination) {
        this.type = type;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }
    
}
```

Also I have 2 more classes that extend from that one. "Conffirmation Connection Message"

```
public class ConnectionConffirmationMessage extends Message{

    public ConnectionConffirmationMessage(int type, String origin, String destination) {
        super(type, origin, destination);
    }

}
```

and "Connection Message"

```
public class ConnectionMessage extends Message{
    
    User info;

    public ConnectionMessage(int type, String origin, String destination, User info) {
        super(type, origin, destination);
        this.info = info;
    }

    public User getInfo() {
        return info;
    }
    
}
```

My problem is that now when I want to ask for the info when the Connection Message arrives I can't. Because the general class "Message" doesn't have the method "getInfo()".

`Message msg = (Message) fin.readObject();`

Any idea of what can I do?

Also, I can't simply change the type because I have this in a while with a switch, so if another type of Message arrives I have to process it.

Comment: What do you mean by " have this in a while with a switch"? Please show a [mcve]. How does this prevent you from casting it?

Comment: You use `if (msg instanceof ConnectionMessage connectionMessage) { connectionMessage.getInfo(); }` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast you message into the specific sub-type

**Before Java 14**

```
if (msg instanceof ConnectionMessage) {
   User user = ((ConnectionMessage) message).getInfo(); 
   // do something with the user
}
```

**After Java 14**

```
if (msg instanceof ConnectionMessage connectionMessage) { 
    User user = connectionMessage.getInfo(); 
    // do something with the user
}
```

In this way, you will call the correct method.

Other solutions would be:

- adding an abstract method to your `Message` class. There you could call method without casting. Disadvantage: You need to implement the abstract method to every subclass of `Message`.
- using reflections and test for the existance of the `getInfo` and call it via reflections. Generally speaking, you should not use reflections, if there is an native java way (like casting)